# jQuery Click Link On Page Load

Tags: jquery, click, onload

I found this code and it is pretty much what I am looking for, except I need the first link to already be selected when the page loads.

```
function CngClass(obj) {
 if (Lst) Lst.className=' ';
obj.className='selected';
Lst=obj;
}



<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- .selected { font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000; } --> 
</style>  
<ul>  
<li>
<a id="homelink" onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Test 1
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Test 2
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Test 3
</a>
</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: selected is just a class name. I want links with that class to be styled differently, and I need the jQuery to add/remove the class depending on which link is clicked on. I have got that far, but I need the first link to already be selected when the page loads.

Comment: see my example at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .selected { font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000; }
</style>  
<ul>  
<li>
    <a id="homelink" href="#">Test 1</a>
</li>  
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
</li>  
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 3</a>
</li>  
​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#homelink").addClass("selected"); //adds selected class in the first link
    $("ul a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe4zS/)

1. Added Selected class to first 'a' in html.
2. bind jQuery click event with each anchor and remove select class from older and add to new on.

   - Test 1
   - Test 2
   - Test 3

   ```
   $("ul a").click(function(){
           $("ul a.selected").removeClass("selected");
           $(this).addClass("selected"); 
           return false;
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this (remove inline onclick event from the `a` tags)

**HTML**

```
<ul>  
<li>
    <a id="homelink" href="#">Test 1</a>
</li>  
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
</li>  
<li>
    <a href="#">Test 3</a>
</li>
```

​
**JS** (keep it between `head` tags wrapped with `script` tags)

```
$(function(){
    $("ul a:first").addClass("selected"); //adds selected class in the first link
    $("ul a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/LApyp/).

Comment: I can't seem to get either of the above methods to work. I'm clueless as to what i'm doing wrong. This is the first time i've really touched upon jQuery. Thanks for the suggestions